# QIcon.fromTheme not displaying icon in PyQt

Tags: python, pyqt, icons, pyqt4, qt-designer

I am having troubles to display the icon of a QAction selected from the current icon theme. I made the ui with Qt designer and exported it with `pyuic4 sample.ui > sample.py`. After setting the icon from the theme with `self.actionSample.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme(_fromUtf8("document-open")))`, I get the following source code :

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    _fromUtf8 = lambda s: s

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("centralwidget"))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtGui.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("statusbar"))
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.toolBar = QtGui.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("toolBar"))
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
        self.actionSample = QtGui.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionSample.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("actionSample"))
        self.actionSample.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme(_fromUtf8("document-open")))
        self.toolBar.addAction(self.actionSample)

        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(window)
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

When I execute it, the toolbar does not display the icon 'document-open'. Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Comment: What plaform are you on, and what version of Qt are you using? Also, did you set the icon in Designer, or add it yourself manually?

Comment: @ekhumoro
I am running :
Gnu/Linux 3.2.0-2-686 - Debian Testing /
Python 2.7.3rc2 /
python-qt4 4.9.3-4 /
I set up the icon manually after generating the `.py` file. But when I generate it with qt-designer it is the same.

Comment: The New Action dialog in the Action Editor should show the icon next to the "Icon theme" property if it's available.

Comment: When I open the Action Editor, I have "document-open" written in the "Icon Theme" text edit. But I don't see any icon.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The icon lookup process used by `QIcon.fromTheme` is somewhat complex.

Icon themes are only directly supported on the X11 platform for the GNOME and KDE desktop environments. For other platforms/desktops, it will be necessary to either install a theme along with the application, or tweak the user's environment in various ways.

To find the current system theme for GNOME, Qt will query gconf (if the gtk style is available), and otherwise default to the "gnome" theme. For KDE, Qt will examine the `kdeglobals` settings file(s), and otherwise default to "oxygen" (or "crystalsvg" for earlier versions of KDE). In addition, the "hicolor" theme can always be used as a fallback.

Once the system theme name has been determined, Qt will look for the directory containing the icons in various pre-determined places, which again depend on both the platform and desktop being used. On X11, this includes `$HOME/.icons` and `$XDG_DATA_DIRS/icons`. The only location common to all platforms/desktops is the resource path `:/icons`.

Icon theme directories must include an `index.theme` file, which (amongst other things) specifies the subdirectories that can contain icons. Only icon files with a `png` or `svg` extension are used.

The `QIcon` class has some static methods which will show exactly where Qt is looking for themed icons:

```
>>> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>>> app = QtGui.QApplication([])
>>> for path in QtGui.QIcon.themeSearchPaths():
...     print "%s/%s" % (path, QtGui.QIcon.themeName())
... 
/home/ekhumoro/.icons/hicolor
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
:/icons/hicolor
```

If the "document-open" icon isn't being displayed, Qt is either looking in the "wrong" place, or the icon is missing altogether.

**UPDATE:**

As I said above: by default, Qt only supports GNOME and KDE on the X11 platform. It doesn't know anything about FluxBox WM, and so cannot detect the current icon theme. This means it will fall back to using a minimal "hicolor" theme, which may not have all the required icons.

One way to solve this issue, is to create a "hicolor" symlink that points to the theme you want to use. Ideally, this should go in the location that is first in Qt's list of search paths:

```
$ ln -s icon/theme/directory $HOME/.icons/hicolor
```

**UPDATE 2**:

Qt5 still only supports kde and gnome by default, but the [Qt Platform Abstraction layer](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpa.html) at least makes it possible to create custom theme plugins ([LXQT](http://lxqt.org/) is one desktop environment that takes advantage of this). There are also several more DE's that are now treated as gtk/gnome: X-CINNAMON, UNITY, MATE, XFCE and LXDE.

Comment: I am running FluxBox WM. When I execute the fragment of code above, I get :


`/home/ben/.icons/hicolor
/usr/local/share/icons/hicolor
/usr/share/icons/hicolor
:/icons/hicolor`


Icons are located in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor` along with the index.theme so it should work right ?

Comment: Ok, I changed the theme with the `setThemeName` static method to one in my `.icons` and it worked well. Any Idea why PyQt does not look into the other search paths ?

Answer (score 1):

Provided that `self` points to something `QWidget`-like you can use this ugly hack:

```py
openIcon = self.style().standardIcon(QStyle.StandardPixmap.SP_FileDialogStart)
openAction(openIcon, 'Open', self)
```

Or, you can also access `.style()` on a `QApplication` instance, i.e. `icon = app.style().standardIcon(...)`.