# How to customize QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt

I would like to be able to select multiple `QComboBox`'s items from its pull-down menu (with Shift or Alt+click to add/extract to-from current selection).

1. On a click QComboBox rolls down a pull-down menu.
2. But when the user makes a second mouse click (picking an item from pull-down menu)

ComboBox wouldn't roll-back (or self-collapse) as it does by default. Instead it would stay open so the user is able to Shift+click more Combobox items to add or to extract them from selection. Finally when the user is happy with the selection the `Enter` key is pressed to "confirm" the selection.

Here is a Photoshoped image showing the concept of "multi-selection" QComboBox I would like to achieve:

[image]

The code below creates QComboBox with almost every event exposed. But the only one I see "acting" is onMousePressEvent(). I can't find the way to track down when the user selects the item from pull-down menu....

## Edit:

Hour later I learned that `QComboBox` can be set to multi selection via its `.view().setSelectionMode(3)`.

Then the same `.view()` could be used to query Combobox selected items:

```
selectedIndexes=self.view().selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
```

*(where `self` is a combo itself)*

There is a way to select the Combo items using `selectionModel.select(idx, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)`

But so far I was not able to make it.....

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
class Combo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Combo, self).__init__()
        self.addItems(['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5'])
        self.view=self.view()
        self.view.setSelectionMode(3)
        self.activated.connect(self.clicked)   
        self.show()

    def clicked(self, arg=None):
        selectionModel=self.view.selectionModel()
        selectedIndexes=selectionModel.selectedIndexes()

        for idx in selectedIndexes:
            selectionModel.select(idx, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)
            print 'selecting idx: %s'%idx

        self.showPopup()

tree=Combo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Other way, your can use just-like icon to check state. To easy than `QtGui.QStandardItem`. The method [`QIcon QComboBox.itemIcon (self, int index)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#itemIcon) and method [`QComboBox.setItemIcon (self, int index, QIcon icon)`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html#setItemIcon) are available in class [`QtGui.QComboBox`](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qcombobox.html);

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class QCustomComboBox (QtGui.QComboBox):
    CHECK_QICON   = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme('call-start')
    UNCHECK_QICON = QtGui.QIcon.fromTheme('call-stop')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(QCustomComboBox, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        listsItem = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3', 'Item 4', 'Item 5']
        for index in range(0, len(listsItem)):
            self.addItem(listsItem[index])
            self.setItemIcon(index, self.UNCHECK_QICON)
        self.activated.connect(self.customActivated)

    def hidePopup (self):
        pass # Force only ESC button to exit.

    def customActivated (self, index):
        # self.blockSignals(True) # Force first index only
        # self.setCurrentIndex(0)
        # self.blockSignals(False)
        stateQIcon = self.itemIcon(index)
        newQIcon = {
            self.CHECK_QICON.name()   : self.UNCHECK_QICON,
            self.UNCHECK_QICON.name() : self.CHECK_QICON,
        } [stateQIcon.name()]
        self.setItemIcon(index, newQIcon)
        print self.export() # View last update data

    def export (self):
        listsExportItem = []
        for index in range(0, self.count()):
            stateQIcon = self.itemIcon(index)
            state = {
                self.CHECK_QICON.name()   : True,
                self.UNCHECK_QICON.name() : False,
            } [stateQIcon.name()]
            listsExportItem.append([str(self.itemText(index)), state])
        return listsExportItem

myQApplication = QtGui.QApplication([])
myQCustomComboBox = QCustomComboBox()
myQCustomComboBox.show()
sys.exit(myQApplication.exec_())
```

Comment: I like the icon idea...couple questions. 1. What is the purpose of `export()` method? 2. The custom ComboBox should allow to multi-select items from its pull-down menu. Using ComoboBox from your code I only able to check one (single) item at the time. Clicking one item unchecks all others (just like default ComboBox does). Please advise.

Comment: (1) For export data in item, just like get state is check or uncheck in each item in `QtGui.QComboBox`.

(2) Is it not work in OSX ? `def hidePopup (self): pass` is it not work ? I use in Ubuntu 12, It work fine, can multi-selected.

Comment: I love `def hidePopup(self):pass`!!! Absolutely beautiful. No need to mess around with `setSetCurrentIndex(0);self.showPopup()` and etc But `export()` method is not working on my mac... not a big deal i think... Thanks for the hidePopup() trick!

Comment: What widget/function/method calls `export()` method? I can't see it is linked to anything in a code... Is it a "built-in" QComboBox method?

Comment: No, It just export data not use in user interface. But if your want to know want to know current state all item. Your just call this, and your can known it. Your can try, put `self.export()` not last line of `def customActivated (self, index):`, your will understand.

Comment: It appears the reason I don't see the icon is because OSX issues. Here is a link to a discussion started earlier on the same subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12825838/1107049

Comment: In the other-hand, not use default icon, create your icon own and put it in `QCustomComboBox` ; )

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using the text colors to differentiate clicked (aka selected) items from others.

First click on ComboBox opens its pull-down menu.
All following clicks are to select/deselect (highlighted red) items. Hit escape to close pull-down.

[image]

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
app = QtGui.QApplication([])

class Combo(QtGui.QComboBox):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Combo, self).__init__()        
        for each in ['Item_1','Item_2','Item_3','Item_4','Item_5']:
            item=QtGui.QStandardItem(each) 
            self.model().appendRow(item)
            item.setData('black')

        self.activated.connect(self.clicked)   
        self.show()  

    def clicked(self, clickedNumber=None): 
        self.blockSignals(True)  
        self.setCurrentIndex(0)        
        self.showPopup()
        self.view().clearSelection()

        clickedItem=self.model().item(clickedNumber)

        color=clickedItem.data().toString()
        if color=='black': clickedItem.setData('red')
        elif color=='red': clickedItem.setData('black')
        clickedItem.setForeground(QtGui.QColor(clickedItem.data().toString()))

        clickedIndex=self.model().indexFromItem(clickedItem)
        self.view().selectionModel().select(clickedIndex, QtGui.QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        self.setCurrentIndex(clickedNumber)  

        self.blockSignals(False)

tree=Combo()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```